# Should we concern about too many bundles in a Pulsar topic?

Tags: apache-pulsar

We observed the following warning in our Pulsar cluster. Shall we concern about it?

```
     18:37:37.165 [pulsar-modular-load-manager-29-1] 
       WARN  org.apache.pulsar.brok er.loadbalance.BundleSplitStrategy - 
       Could not split namespace bundle pulsareval/0x56000000_0x56800000
       because namespace pulsareval has too many bundles: 512
```

Answer (score 4):

***First some background on what bundles actually are...***
from https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/administration-load-balance/#creating-namespaces-and-bundles

Instead of being assigned to an individual topic, each Pulsar broker takes ownership of a subset of the topics for a namespace. This subset is called a "bundle" and effectively it's a sharding mechanism.

Topics are assigned to a particular bundle by taking the hash of the topic name and seeing in which bundle the hash falls into. Each bundle is independent of the others and thus is independently assigned to different brokers.

In general, if the expected traffic and number of topics is known in advance, it's a good idea to start with a reasonable number of bundles instead of waiting for the system to auto-correct the distribution.

***Namespace bundles splitting***

Since the load for the topics in a bundle might change over time, or could just be hard to predict upfront, bundles can be split in 2 by brokers. The new smaller bundles can then be reassigned to different brokers.

Your error message indicates that the number of topics grew enough to trigger the automatic splitting of the bundles, but that failed do to the maximum number of bundles allowed in a namespace. While this is a non-fatal condition, it will impact performance.

Therefore you might want to increase the value of the `loadBalancerNamespaceMaximumBundles` property in your broker.conf file which limits the maximum number of bundles you can have in a namespace. Based on the error message it appears that is what is happening.

Comment: David can you clarify why having too many bundles impacts performance? Thanks!

Comment: In order to support the splitting algorithms I mentioned, various performance metrics such as msg/sec, avg latency, etc are tracked at the bundle level. This helps Pulsar identify the proper bundle to "split" based on the load. The tracking of these metrics does incur some performance cost in terms of memory and network, as they are stored in the metadata store (ZooKeeper). Therefore, it is best to minimize the number of bundles in order to minimize this impact. That is why the default behavior is to start at a relatively small number of bundles and let the number grow organically.